# Change order of txt file lines divided by ":" using awk or cut

Tags: awk, terminal, grep, cut, gnuwin32

I have a text file called: example.txt which contains these lines:

```
email1:location1
email2:location2
email3:location3
```

I want to change it up to look like this:

```
location1:email1 
location2:email2 
location3:email3
```

What would be the easiest way to do this? I tried several awk commands, but couldnt get them to work. From what I read so far, its not possible with cut. 
I am using Ubuntu or GNUwin32 on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
awk -F : 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { print $2, $1 }' filename
```

The only trick here is that the output field separator`OFS` needs to be set to the field separator `FS` (that `-F :` sets to `:`) so the fields are separated the same way in the output as in the input. `$2` refers to the second field in the line, `$1` to the first.

Also possible:

```
awk -F : '{ print $2 ":" $1 }' filename
```

...at the cost of having to change the call in two places to use it with a different separator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one `awk`

```
awk -F: '$0=$2":"$1' file
location1:email1
location2:email2
location3:email3
```

`-F:` sets field separator to `:`
`$0=$2":"$1` reconstruct line by using field `2` before field `1`
Since this always will be true, it also will do the default action, print the line.